# custom font wont show up in page hostgator

Tags: html, css, fonts, ftp, styles

Hi I have a problem with my fonts. I have downloaded a custom font online (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and I want it to appear on my page. It worked perfectly fine when I tried to upload it on a different ftp server but when I tried to upload it in hostgator, it won't show up. I have tried to upload my site in a different ftp server and everything worked fine, just when I tried to upload it in hostgator, the fonts wont show up. I have separate css file uploaded and it looks something like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'quicksandregular';
src: url('../font/Quicksand/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/Quicksand/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/Quicksand/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/Quicksand/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('quicksand-regular-webfont.svg#quicksandregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

and for the style css:

```
#about p.content a, #works p.content a, #preloader p.content a {
color: #ffffff;
font: 17px 'Quicksandregular';
text-decoration: underline;
```

}

and my index page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/quicksand.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and check if your font resources are loaded. If they doesn't you should have something like [image] but 5 instead 1 errors.
Also, in your style.css file replace `font: 17px 'Quicksandregular';` with `font-family: 'Quicksandregular';font-size: 17px;` and check if the problem persist. Your syntax is right too, but just for be sure.
Check your path to files very carefully to make sure you did not forget anything.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for answering. Unfortunately I have 12 errors and they say : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Those errors means that the server fails to access the font files, and it will not be applied. Can you provide me a screenshot with these errors please? I must see them all to try to give you a solution.

Comment: I already fixed them. It's just the Quicksand folder should be in lowercase "quicksand" that was why it cannot be loaded and also I didn't take a look closely. All the paths and codes were right. Thanks for your help!!! :)